# How to refactor a file namespace?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, automated-refactoring

I have a N-Layer project and when im defining the ContextBounderies i use to change it during the needs of the development. For example i have this class:

```
namespace Domain.Entities.Item
public class ItemForSale
{

}
```

This class is now inside the `Entites/Item` folder in the solution. But during the development I realize that this class will make more sense inside the `Sell` folder, so the namespace should be `namespace Domain.Entities.Sell`. Well, the problem is that i have lots of references of this class in a number of layers projects, so its always a pain to refactor it by hand.

Is there a way to configure it, or some free extension (resharper do that but its not for free) wich do this job?

Im using `Visual Studio 2015`
Thanks!

Comment: You don't _have_ to have the namespaces match the folders.  Some tools will let you know if there is a mismatch and give you an option to fix it but it is not requirement.  If you're asking for a tool reocmmendation then that is explicitly off topic for SO.

Comment: Yes, but when i create a class inside this folder VS automatically sets the namespace matching the current folder.

Comment: I know you don't want "Resharper" as the answer, but it really is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is just a feature of VS2015. You can right click on the namespace you want to change, and then select the "Rename" options under the drop-down. It will update all of the references inside of the solution. So, if you have multiple projects inside of your solution, they will all get updated with the new name.

(Also, there is a keyboard shortcut as well. You can click the namespace you want to change, and then press F2 on your keyboard to bring up the Rename menu.)

Comment: Actually, as of VS2015, you cannot rename to a multi-part namespace (this worked, for the most part, in earlier versions)

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is not frequent then you can use **Replace in Files** option to replace all old namespace occurences to new ones. Just use <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, fill appropriate fields and select **Look in** option to look in **Entire solution**.